# Why doesn't Cyanogenmod show the update for CM11-M4 in the Cyanogen Updater?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, samsung-galaxy-s-4, samsung-galaxy-s-3-mini, cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-4-mini

On my phone when I do a CM update, no matter what I chose to show the update for M4 isn't available? What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

CM11-M4 didn't ship for the `jf` or `d2` phones (Galaxy S4 and S3). They were not ready. It'll be back for `-M5`. All of the `jftle-` builds were concentrated [into one Unified Device build](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Jflte_Info).

> **Note: Unified device**
>
> Soon after the release of CM 11 M3, all Qualcomm-based variants of this device were merged into a single build: jflte. The device information pages for the individual variants still exist so that you can reference any device-specific unlock instructions, download recoveries, or would like to build, for example, CM 10.2: jflteatt, jfltecan, jfltecri, jfltecsp, jfltespr, jfltetmo, jflteusc, jfltevzw, jfltexx.

This new build, simply [`jftle` has no M4 available on the website](http://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=jflte&type=milestone) either, it's not just the updater.

And, just for comprehensiveness the [`jftlespr` (the Sprint Deprecated variant)](http://download.cyanogenmod.org/?type=snapshot&device=jfltespr) also doesn't have the M4 build.

Here is what was said in `irc.freenode.net/#cyanogenmod`,

```
< [R]> jf and d2 weren't ready for m4
< [R]> so they didnt get it
< EvanCarroll> [R]: Thanks for the update!
< EvanCarroll> [R]: is there a post about that, and will they get -M4 later, will they get -M5 or will they be supported in CM11?
< [R]> of course they dont get it
< [R]> of course there will be m5
< [R]> i said it wans't ready for m4
< [R]> i dindt say cm is dropping it
```